# How to convert a jquery object to JSON string OR how to save a specific element in a string?

Tags: jquery, json, jquery-selectors

I added a click event to all elements on the page and now want to send the clicked target element to a server.
If the clicked element has an ID, then I can just send the ID, but if the element doesn't have an ID, class, name, ... , then how can I send an identifier (or selector) to the server which points to this exact element?

I tried sending the jquery.target object itself. However, this results in a 
"Uncaught TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON"
error.

Is there a way to serialize a jquery object or to create a selector based on the current element?

Comment: why do you need to send an identifier to the exact element? Do you have have the ability to amend how the HTML is generated? If so, I'd be inclined to give all elements an id if you need to do this, but I'm sure there are better ways to achieve the particular problem you want to solve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At least for form elements I managed to get a working version by creating a selector string from the target's parents and then adding the input type and its name attribute, e.g.:

```
var target_selector = $(e.target).parents().map(function () { return this.tagName; }).get();
target_selector.reverse();
target_selector.push(e.target.tagName);
target_selector = target_selector.join('>');
target_selector = target_selector + '[name=\'' + $(e.target).attr('name') + '\']';
```

This does the trick at least for input elements.